# Rest endpoint authentication response

Tags: rest, authentication, restful-authentication

If I have a RESTful endpoint for authentication such as

Www.example.com/login

Does it make sense to return more than user info.  For example can I return

Username, email, peers **AND** also return a list of loans or other business specific data which also returned from another endpoint.

Or should I make another http request to

Example.com/dataEndpoint

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to provide a valid answer, so here's a high level attempt at one...

Are you trying to implement one of the authentication standards (OAUTH, SAML, Any one of the certificate based ones), or something custom?

If you are trying to implement a standard, then you need to follow that standard for the login/authentication endpoints.

If you are writing your own custom protocol, then its up to you but I'd recommend you not overload any endpoint with too many different responsibilities as it will become harder to maintain over time.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Dan!  I implemented my own custom login endpoint that is unrelated to OAuth etc. I am simply returning a user object and I am wondering if I can return other business data as well or if it is a bad practice and I should perform another api call for the business domain data

Comment: My feeling is that it would be bad practice, it makes it harder for anyone (including you) to maintain this longer term as it mixes two (or more) concerns into a single place. Best practices tend to boil down to SOLID, and single responsibility is first for a reason ;)